# Remove elements from a tuple with conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, filtering, gathering

I have a tuple `mytup`.
Assume two arbitrary elements from the tuples are `{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9}` and `{b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9}`.

Now I want to delete the element that satisies the condition:

```
a1 = b1
a2 = -b2
a3 = b3
a4 = b4
a5 = -b5
a6 = b6
a7 = b7 
a8 = -b8
a9 = -b9
```

and the deleted element should have `a8 = -1` and `a9 = 1`.
I tried using `Gather` and `First` to select the first element from each group but this does not work as the element with `a8 = -1` and `a9 = 1` is not always placed first in the group. 
Is there a good way to do this?

UPDATE: from my tuple below, all elements have `a8 = 1` and `a9 = -1` or `a8 = -1` and `a9 = 1`. However, the bigger data may include pairs with `a8`, and `a9` are not plus or minus 1 and no element from this pair is deleted.
For example, both `{0, -1, -1, 1, 0, -1, d, 2, 3}, {0, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1, d, -2,  -3}` are kept.

```
  mytup = {{0, -1, -1, 1, 0, -1, d, 0, 1}, {0, -1, -1, 1, 0, -1, d, 1, 
    0}, {0, -1, -1, 1, 0, -1, d, 1, -1}, {0, -1, -1, 1, 0, -1, d, -1, 
    1}, {0, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, d, 0, 1}, {0, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, d, 1, 
    0}, {0, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, d, -1, 1}, {0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, d, 0, 
    1}, {0, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, d, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, d, 0, 
    1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, d, -1, 1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, d, 0, 
    1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, d, -1, 1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, d, 0, 
    1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, d, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, d, 
    1, -1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, d, -1, 1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, d, 0, 
    1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, d, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, d, 
    1, -1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, d, -1, 1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, d, 0, 
    1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, d, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, d, 
    1, -1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, d, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, d, 1, 
    0}, {0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, d, 1, -1}, {0, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1, d, 
    1, -1}, {0, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1, d, -1, 1}, {0, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0, d, 1, 
    0}, {0, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0, d, 1, -1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, d, 0, 
    1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, d, 1, 0}, {1, -1, -1, 1, 0, -1, d, 0, 
    1}, {1, -1, -1, 1, 0, -1, d, 1, 0}, {1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, d, 0, 
    1}, {1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, d, 1, 0}, {1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, d, -1, 
    1}, {1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, d, 1, -1}, {1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, d, -1, 
    1}, {1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, d, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, d, 1, 
    0}, {1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, d, 1, -1}, {1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, d, -1, 
    1}, {1, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, d, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, d, 1, 
    0}, {1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, d, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, d, 1, 
    0}, {1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, d, 1, -1}, {1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, d, -1, 
    1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, d, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, d, 1, -1}};
gathered = 
  Gather[mytup, ((#1[[1]] == #2[[1]]) && (#1[[2]] == -#2[[2]]) && \
(#1[[3 ;; 4]] == #2[[3 ;; 
           4]]) && (#1[[5]] == -#2[[5]]) && (#1[[6]] == #2[[6]]) && \
(#1[[7]] == #2[[7]]) && (#1[[8]] == -#2[[8]]) && (#1[[9]] == \
-#2[[9]])) &];
result = Map[First]@gathered
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete both elements `{a1, a2, ...}` and `{b1, b2, ...}` if they're related in that way? Or just one of them?

Comment: @thorimur just one of them but the one with `a8 = -1` and `a9 = 1`. I just added some update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think one way to do this is:

```
Select[mytup,
  !(#[[8]] == -1
    && #[[9]] == 1
    && MemberQ[mytup, # * {1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1}])
   &]
```

This keeps exactly the ones that fail the criterion, i.e. deletes the ones that *do* satisfy having their 8th part be `-1`, their 9th part be `1`, and such that the list contains some member equal to `{1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1}` times the considered element.

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thanks, it works. The `MemberQ` is nice. Is that `*` the multiplication? I think it should be but just for sure.

Comment: Yes, it is! When you multiply lists of equal length, Mathematica automatically threads the multiplication over the lists componentwise.